# how to use hibernate deal with Dictionary Data

Tags: hibernate

In my project,there are many dict info:

```
@Entity
@Table
class Dict{
   String type; 
   String value;
   String desc;
   boolean valid;
}

@Entity
@Table
class User{
   String name;
   Dict post;
   Dict staffType;
   ....
}
```

How to mapping these Dict entity? 
I don't want to use composite primary key, that will create tow foreignKeys with one field.

Comment: Are you asking for advice on your database architecture, help with your Hibernate mappings, or both?

Comment: I ask for a good way to deal with this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement primary keys for each entity, and map with a one-to-many relationship: [See the Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#d5e5756).